# Unable to divide a row into two column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put some content and a image equally inside a row. 
Basically I want to divide a row into two column.

But the text inside paragraph is taking the full width and thus the image falls out of space and is displayed in next row.

here is my code

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class"col-md-6">
                <div class="h3">Hazel</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras volutpat nulla et luctus scelerisque. Fusce purus enim, auctor non molestie sit amet, congue non eros. Suspendisse bibendum volutpat magna, vel blandit velit ornare a. Fusce vitae lectus a purus ullamcorper consequat.</p><p> Maecenas porta maximus porttitor. Sed ac ipsum faucibus, egestas eros vitae, feugiat nisl. Ut vel odio vel massa iaculis porttitor. Nunc tincidunt nunc et molestie commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed tristique dapibus diam, at tristique purus tincidunt vitae. Donec fringilla tempor lectus quis sodales. Sed non dapibus felis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img/saree1.png">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution : use `style="display: inline-block;`

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class"col-md-6" style="display: inline-block;>
                <div class="h3">Hazel</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras volutpat nulla et luctus scelerisque. Fusce purus enim, auctor non molestie sit amet, congue non eros. Suspendisse bibendum volutpat magna, vel blandit velit ornare a. Fusce vitae lectus a purus ullamcorper consequat.</p><p> Maecenas porta maximus porttitor. Sed ac ipsum faucibus, egestas eros vitae, feugiat nisl. Ut vel odio vel massa iaculis porttitor. Nunc tincidunt nunc et molestie commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed tristique dapibus diam, at tristique purus tincidunt vitae. Donec fringilla tempor lectus quis sodales. Sed non dapibus felis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="display: inline-block;>
                <img src="img/saree1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitatcs/zhhqejvr/)

Comment: Try this : in style - { overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;}

Comment: style="word-wrap: break-word;"